# Unrecognized option: - Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am trying to run my `.jar` file on a linux server.

These are the commands I'm running:

```
JAVA_HOME=/app/local/opt/jdk/packages/jdk1.6.0_30/ 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 

cd folder
nohup java -jar program.jar &
```

When ran on Friday, this was working perfectly. However, today I am getting:

```
  Unrecognised option: - Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

In my nohup.out

If I run `java -v` after setting the path I get the same problem. Can anyone suggest anything? Really confused about this.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you using the same user? Are you working in the same directory `folder`?

Comment: does it work without using nohup?  maybe some other error such as disk space/permissions etc.

Comment: No it does not. I am in the correct directory. I literally am doing the same thing I was doing Friday and it was working.
It must be something to do with java or java - v would wokr righT?

Comment: In my mac, java only supports `java -version` other than `java -v`

Answer (score 21):

Usually, when we get this kind of exception ("Unrecognised option" which causes the "Could not create the Java virtual machine"), the JVM displays the unrecognized option, like this:

```
Unrecognised option: -[option details] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

the fact that you have no details makes it seem as though you just have a space (" ") in your command.

Take a look again to make sure.

Comment: Not sure that's an answer.

Comment: It is an answer.  Not necessarily the correct one, but it is definitely an answer.

Comment: awesome call, yes, thats an answer

Comment: For me it just says `Unrecognized option: -jar /home/administrator/Desktop/MyApp.jar` what is wrong with these java options please?

Answer (score 6):

I've got this failure running maven on Win10 where the pom.xml is located in a folder named something like `C:\dir\OneDrive - bar\workspace\project`.

Moving the project to a different folder solved it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is no `-v` option on the `java` command.

(Reference:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html ... Java 6 version ... 'cos that is what you are using.  Try `java -help` for the short list of options.)

So it is expected for `java -v` to fail.

As an experiment I tried this (with an OpenJDK Java 8 JDK on Fedora 22):

```
$ java -foop
Unrecognized option: -foop
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
$
```

As you can see, the "unrecognized option" message tells me what option it doesn't understand.  Looking at the message in your question, we see that it is saying it is "-".  That doesn't appear to match the command line in your question, but on the other hand the command line in your question does not have any invalid options.

Another possibility, I guess, is that you have a shell alias called `java`.  That would take precedence over any commands on the shell's command path.

The other thing is that you are running an ancient version of Java.  Java 6 has passed end-of-life, and the last publicly released version is update 45.  You are running update 30 which was released in December 2011.  There have been LOTS of security patches since then.  I'd recommend upgrading to Java 8 ... and making sure that you keep it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

for java 8 run 'java -version'
for java 9 or 9+ run 'java --version'

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue under Linux/Ubuntu 20.04.

I created a bash to run my jar and used some variables in the file

```bash
# This line below shows the error
$JAVA_PATH "-jar $JVM_ARGS $JAR_PATH"

# This line below runs without issue
$JAVA_PATH "-jar" $JVM_ARGS $JAR_PATH $SB_ARGS
```

I don't know why it works after using double quotes for the "-jar" option only, I think it's something to do with UNIX systems.