# Using CPLEX Java API in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, cplex

I have a problem when using CPLEX 12.6 in Netbeans 8.1.  I added the cplex126 library in Netbeans, wrote optimization code, and ran it.  It solved the problem to optimality and the solution appears in the output.

But when I add the path below in VM options:
`-Djava.library.path=/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx`

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -
C:\Users\A.OMIDI\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Is it really necessary to add the path to VM options? (Without it, the problem is solved)

Comment: This question was crossposted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=08c61453-01ae-4757-ab43-0f0bccfc6a45#db15d1a8-3866-4f6a-8c9e-b29b590cd872).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089750/unrecognized-option-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine), do you happen to have any spaces in your VM options entry?  As to why it's working without the VM options, is it possible that `/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio126/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx` is already in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945268/difference-between-using-java-library-path-and-ld-library-path))?  If it's working there's nothing wrong with leaving it alone (but, there is a possibility that you're not pointing at exactly the library you want; for example, a different version).  However, it's always better to understand *why* something is happening (especially if you want to deploy your program to other systems).